# How to configure Jboss AS 7 with Nginx in windows 7 environment

Tags: java, jboss, nginx, load-balancing, httpserver

Can any one point to step by step guide to configure n jboss AS7 enterprise app with nginx.
Suppose if i have 
webserver path: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\
deployed @ C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\HelloWorld.deployed
AppContext url :   `http://localhost:9090/HelloWorld`

I want all request coming to nginx :80 to direct to

```
http://localhost:9090/HelloWorld
```

Note:

I reffered 
https://serverfault.com/questions/293348/configure-nginx-for-jboss-tomcat
Which only show a generic info. Can anyone point to actual config for an jboss ear app deployed in Standalone mode in Jboss AS7 (app is not deployed as exploded version).

Comment: Hi, did you manage to get anywhere with this? We have a similar setup and issue.

Answer (score 0):

Config like this would proxy localhost:80 on nginx to localhost:9090/HelloWorld/ on jboss

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost; # or any other logical name
    client_max_body_size 10m; # not needed but useful
    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main; 

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:9090/HelloWorld/;
        proxy_redirect default;
    }    
}
```